# suspendCoroutine is not resolving

Tags: android, kotlin, kotlin-coroutines

`import kotlin.coroutines.suspendCoroutine` is not resolving in my android kotlin project

kotlin version -  `'1.8.10'`

```
id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.android' version "1.8.10" apply false
```

I added below entries as well in gradle file

```
implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:$kotlin_version"
implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-core:$kotlin_version"
```

Can anyone point out the missing deps / pieces here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need either of those, it's in the stdlib. Make sure the Kotlin plugin is applied correctly (i.e. you can resolve other things from the stdlib) and you should be fine.

If it still doesn't work, make sure your IDE is up to date with Gradle config.

Comment: Thanks . It was resolved after the android studio update.